# LUA, multiple number string to number

Tags: json, split, lua, lua-table, roblox

so I use web to request json:

```
{"number":"1,2,3"} OR table = {number="1,2,3"}
```

and when I used this, it shows number:

```
typeof(1,2,3)
```

but when i directly get the data from the json/table, it shows string, so is there anyway to convert it to show it as number?

Comment: Did you try to split the string and use `tonumber`?

Comment: You can put the `tonumber()` function into a variable with your selected number.

Answer (score 1):

A Lua pattern might also a good choice to get the numbers from the raw string; then use tonumber() as suggested and add the numbers to a table in the sample code as shown below:

```
numbers = {}
str = '1,2,3'
for num in string.gmatch(str, '([^,]+)') do
    table.insert(numbers, tonumber(num))
end
```

Comment: If the numbers are integers, then the pattern can be `'%d+'`.